# vis.js: remove property of item in dataset

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I am using the [vis.js visualization library](http://visjs.org/). I have a [vis.js dataset](http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html) that was instantiated using

```
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, label: 'Item 1', group: "special"},
    {id: 2, label: 'Item 2'},
}
```

I would like to remove the group "special". Afterwards, the state of the dataset should be identical to a dataset that was instantiated without a group:

```
var nodes2 = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, label: 'Item 1'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Item 2'},
}
```

**How do you remove a property from an item within a dataset object, without removing the item itself?**

---

Methods I have tested without success: `nodes.update({id:1, groups: undefined})` `nodes.update({id:1, groups: null})`, `nodes.update({id:1, groups: 0})`

Comment: Did you try this: `nodes.update({id:1, label: 'Item 1'})`

Comment: @Mojtaba just did. does not work. update adds and overwrites attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vis JS, merges values of objects, thus only adding / modifying new values but not removing existing ones. I ended up with remove / insert logic. In your case I would do:

```
const nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, label: 'Item 1', group: "special"},
  {id: 2, label: 'Item 2'},
}

const nodeId = 1;
const propertyToRemove = 'group';
// get a node
const node = nodes.get(nodeId);
// remove property
delete node[propertyToRemove];

// get positions (only for nodes with x and y coordinates)
// only if x and y are not present on original node
const coordinates = vis.Network.getPositions([nodeId])[nodeId];
// copy coordinates
node = Object.assign(node, coordinates); 

// remove node
nodes.remove(nodeId);
// add cloned node
nodes.add(node);
```

you can write this code as function on `vis.DataSet.prototype` for convenience